# Major differences to note when upgrading from Canon 60D to 6D

Tags: canon, canon-60d, canon-6d

Aside from obviously the the 60D and 6D being APS-C and Full Frame respectively, What are the main features or new controls that must be learnt about when using the canon 6D to truly master the cameras capabilities, that are not available on a canon 60D?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the "obvious" change here should not be underestimated.
After my recent switch from APS-C (Canon) to full frame (Nikon) even with the brand change and the different user interface my biggest challenge are implications of DOF and the fact that because of that the focusing needs to be much more exact.

Answer (score 1):

In Canon 6D you can set up AF micro adjustments for lenses you have. That may improve sharpness a bit.

There is also ISO 50 mode that is turned of by default.

Comment: Note tha the ISO 50-mode is an expanded one and not a "real" setting. You will get the same effect by overexposing and bringing exposure down in post.

Comment: @Hugo thanks, I didn't know about that.